# Read a specified line of text from a webpage with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, screen-scraping

So I am trying to get the data from [this webpage](http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=Lynx%A0Titan) using Jsoup...

I've tried looking up many different ways of doing it and I've gotten close but I don't know how to find tags for certain stats (*Attack*, *Strength*, *Defence*, etc.)

So let's say for examples sake I wanted to print out

```
'Attack', '15', '99', '200,000,000'
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Try to make your question clearer and show sufficient research effort. Otherwise you won't get much help here. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) in [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to easily extract the column data.

```
// retrieve page source code
Document doc = Jsoup
        .connect("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=Lynx%A0Titan")
        .get();

// find all of the table rows
Elements rows = doc.select("div#contentHiscores table tr");
ListIterator<Element> itr = rows.listIterator();

// loop over each row
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Element row = itr.next();

    // does the second col contain the word attack?
    if (row.select("td:nth-child(2) a:contains(attack)").first() != null) {

        // if so, assign each sibling col to variable
        String rank = row.select("td:nth-child(3)").text();
        String level = row.select("td:nth-child(4)").text();
        String xp = row.select("td:nth-child(5)").text();

        System.out.printf("rank=%s level=%s xp=%s", rank, level, xp);

        // stop looping rows, found attack
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very rough implementation would be as below. I have just shown a snippet , optimizations or other conditionals need to be added

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=Lynx%A0Titan")
            .get();
    Element contentHiscoresDiv = doc.getElementById("contentHiscores");
    Element table = contentHiscoresDiv.child(0);
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        for (Element column : tds) {
            if (column.children() != null && column.children().size() > 0) {
                Element anchorTag = column.getElementsByTag("a").first();
                if (anchorTag != null && anchorTag.text().contains("Attack")) {
                    System.out.println(anchorTag.text());
                    Elements attributeSiblings = column.siblingElements();
                    for (Element attributeSibling : attributeSiblings) {
                        System.out.println(attributeSibling.text());

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attack

15
99
200,000,000

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, but how would I be able to declare each one as a String, so String rank is 15, String level is 99, String XP is 200,000,000?

Comment: No need to nest for loops if you use selectors.